# A drawing of a right triangle is not displayed properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a right triangle APR, with the right angle at A. Why is the right angle mark not at A?  Why are several of the angle marks not centered about a vertex of the triangle?  I draw an altitude of the triangle from A.  I want to mark the length as h, for height, but I don't want the lines above and below h.  How do I get that.  Why do I have "h" printed near P?!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},line width=.7pt]
\path
  (80:5) node[dot,label=above left:$A$]{} coordinate (A)
  (80:7) coordinate (a)
  (20:9) coordinate (B)
  (20:11) coordinate (b)
  (0:0) node[dot,label=below left:$P$]{} coordinate(P)
  (-100:1)coordinate (e)
  (-160:1)coordinate (f)
  ($(P)!(A)!(B)$)node[dot,label=below:$Q$]{} coordinate(Q);

\path[name path=kline](f)--(b); % First line for intersection
\path[name path=ARline](A)--($(A)!10cm!90:(P)$); % A line normal to pA at point A in the east direction

\path [name intersections={of = ARline and kline, by=R}];
\draw (A)--(P)--(R)node[dot,label=below:$R$]{}--cycle;
\draw[purple!70!black,dashed] (A)--(Q);

\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Q,P);
\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!-7mm!90:(Q)$)--node[fill=white,sloped]{$x$} ($(Q)!-7mm!-90:(P)$);
\draw[<->|] ($(Q)!-7mm!90:(R)$)--node[fill=white,sloped]{$y$} ($(R)!-7mm!-90:(Q)$);
\draw ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white] {$h$} ($(A)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](P,A,Q);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](A,R,P);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=cyan,mark=||](B,P,A);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=cyan,mark=||](Q,A,R);

\tkzMarkRightAngle(R,A,P);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your angle remarks. As per the picture too they look proper. For `h` remark without line, `\path ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$h$} ($(A)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);` (you may prefer not to have `sloped` though). Note `\draw` → `\path`.

Comment: ++@HarishKumar, you can use: `\node at ($(A)!0.5!(Q)$) [fill=white] {$h$};`

Comment: @ferahfeza  What is the syntax `\node at ($(A)!0.5!(Q)$) {$h$};` instructing `TikZ` to draw?

Comment: @Harish Kumar  In the code, I have the following command.    `($(P)!(A)!(B)$)node[dot,label=below:$Q$]{} coordinate(Q);`   Please explain the syntax to me.  Why do we need a pair of dollar signs?  What does the exclamation point after the "P" and after the "A" instruct `TikZ` to draw?

Comment: @Harish Kumar  Do you know the length of each side of the right angle mark in this drawing? I have a diagram of right triangles that are drawn using `tkz-euclide` on another page; I want the right-angle marks that  I have to manually make in this diagram to be identical to the right angle marks drawn by `TikZ`.

Comment: `($(P)!(A)!(B)$)node[dot,label=below:$Q$]{} coordinate(Q);` means → Calculate the projection of point `A` on to the segment `PB` and label it as `Q`. In other words, draw a perpendicular from `A` on to `PB`.  We need `$` while doing calculations on coordinates and `!` is the delimiter kind of thing to separate coordinates inside an expression.

Comment: @Jake  I have a file containing drawings from `TikZ` and `tkz-euclide`.  I would like the right-angle marks to be the same.  Do you know the length of each side of the right-angle mark in a drawing from `TikZ`? I would manually make a square in a drawing of right triangles from `tkz-euclide` to obtain identical right-angle marks.